Rocky Mountains Elevation Cutout
I was wondering whether Mathematica has the data to make a diagram showing a cutout of the Rocky Mountains, showing the elevations from San Francisco, say, to Denver, for example. Something along the lines of this cutout that I found by a search. It seems to be from some tour or race, divided into days but I am not looking for that. I am just looking for what in engineering or architecture would be called an elevation diagram of the Rockies, a line following the surface of the ground through peaks and valleys. I'd like this to include Salt Lace City, to show its plateau. Many thanks in advance.


Use TravelDirections to find a tour from San Francisco, to Salt Lake City, ending in Denver.
cities = {Entity["City", {"SanFrancisco", "California", "UnitedStates"}],
  Entity["City", {"SaltLakeCity", "Utah", "UnitedStates"}],
  Entity["City", {"Denver", "Colorado", "UnitedStates"}]};
td = TravelDirections[cities];
GeoGraphics[{Style[td["TravelPath"], Thick, Red],
  GeoMarker[cities]}]


Use the travel directions (td) to make a list of tour positions, and sample 200 of them as a path. Plot the distances and elevations following the path. Update: changed dist to start at 0 miles; now elev and dist are the same length so Rest@elev isn't needed when plotting.
tour = GeoPosition /@ Flatten[td["TravelPath"][[1, 1]], 1];
path = tour[[Subdivide[1, Length@tour, 199] // Round]];

elev = Normal@GeoElevationData@GeoPosition[LatitudeLongitude[path]];
dist = Prepend[GeoDistanceList[path] // Accumulate,
  Quantity[0, "Miles"]];
lbl = TemplateApply["Tour Length ``, Elevation Change ``",
  {Round@td["TravelDistance"], Round@First@Differences[elev[[{1, -1}]]]}];

ListLinePlot[Transpose[{dist, elev}],
  PlotLabel -> Style[lbl, Black, Larger]]


It's easy to label locations on the path. Using Salt Lake City as an example, locate the point on path that's nearest to the location (any GeoPosition). Find the point's distance along the path (pt1). Use pt1 to label its location on the plot of elevations. This elevation plot shows the flat Salt Lake Basin.
loc1 = Entity["City", {"SaltLakeCity", "Utah", "UnitedStates"}];
locName1 = loc1["Name"];
pt1 = QuantityMagnitude@dist[[First[
  Nearest[path -> "Index", loc1["Position"]]]]];

ListLinePlot[Callout[Transpose[{dist, elev}],
    locName1, {pt1, "Below"}],
  PlotLabel -> Style[lbl, Black, Larger]]


Use LinearGradientFilling to show altitudes as a gradient fill under the elevation plot. ColorData["Gradients"] has other choices to use in place of "AlpineColors".
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{dist, elev}],
  PlotLabel -> Style[lbl, Black, Larger],
  FillingStyle -> LinearGradientFilling["AlpineColors", Top],
  Filling -> Bottom]



This is fantastic. Many thanks! Might it be possible for the component from San Francisco to Salt Lake City to use as a route the Western Pacific railroad? Also, can we fill the area under the line with a gradient of colors showing altitudes?

@NicholasG  There's no Mathematica resource for railroad routes that I can find, and while there are online maps, the data (latitude and longitude) that you'd enter as path is not so easy to find. Try koordinaters.com, or search for "railroad map data" online.

@NicholasG  Good question about gradient filling... Use LinearGradientFilling to show altitude as a gradient. Check these Mathematica Stackexchange posts for solutions. I'll add a gradient plot to my answer.

Many thanks! If it is easy, while you are engaged with this, does an easy way exist to switch the axes' units, for example, to kilometers and meters?

TravelDirections, GeoElevationData and GeoDistanceList have a UnitSystem -> "Metric" option that returns meters and kilometers. Add the option to the definitions of  td, elev and dist.  To be consistent, change Quantity[0, "Miles"] to Quantity[0, "Kilometers"] in the elev definition. Another way is UnitConvert.

Since this question seems to be so popular, let me throw one more way to make the result even better. Can you include the name of the peaks or passes of the cutout? The way the "Independence pass" is marked in the example.

This data is available however it depends a bit on whether you want to follow a particular path (in which case you will need a set of coordinates following roads etc) or directly straight line distance. A simple solution following straight-line distance is:
pos1 = Entity["City", {"SanFrancisco", "California", "UnitedStates"}];
pos2 = Entity["City", {"Denver", "Colorado", "UnitedStates"}];
d = GeoDistance[pos1, pos2];
alpha = GeoDirection[pos1, pos2];
distances = Range[0, d, d/100];
positions = GeoDestination[pos1, {distances, alpha}];
data = GeoElevationData[positions];
ListPlot[Transpose[{distances, data}], Joined -> True]


